# Error Models beyond Additive/Multiplicative for Observables on Bounded Intervals

Tags: references, measurement-error

Arguably, the two most common error models are

| Error Model | Support | Formula | Assumptions | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Additive | $(-∞, +∞)$ | $y_\text{obs} = y + ε$ | $[ε]=0$ $[ε]=σ²$ |  |
| Multiplicative | $(0, +∞)$ | $y_\text{obs} = {(1+ε) y}$ | $[ε]=0$ $[ε]=σ²$ | $ε>-1$ |

The great thing about these error distributions is that $ε$ can be assumed independent of $y$. However, what are appropriate error models to use when measurement data (both $y$ and $y_\text{obs}$) is constrained to:

- a closed, compact interval $[a, b]$ (w.l.o.g. $[0,1]$)
- a compact, half-open interval $[a, b)$. (w.l.o.g. $[0,1)$)
- a half open interval $[0, ∞)$, which cannot be log-transformed because the boundary value occurs frequently.

In particular, are there useful error distributions for such variables that retain the property that $ε$ can be assumed to be independent of $y$?

---

**Note 1**: I do not want to put any assumptions / models on $y$ beyond the restriction to the interval.

**Note 2**: In some of the cases I am looking at, the data could be described as a mixture of a truncated normal distribution on (0,1) and a dirac measure at 0. This makes things like a logit transform problematic. Consequently, when I am talking about a data $y$ on a **closed interval** $[a,b]$, we shall assume that $y$ is distributed according to a mixture

$$p(y) = π_a δ_a(y) + (1-π_a-π_b) \tilde{ω}(y) + π_b δ_b(y)$$

where $\tilde{ω}(y)=\begin{cases}\hfill 0:& y=a\\ω(y) :& y∈(a,b) \\ \hfill 0:& y=b \end{cases}$

For some smooth probability distribution $ω$ on $(0,1)$.

Note that both $π_a$ and $π_b$ are allowed to potentially be zero or non-zero.

Comment: Look into (1) [generalized linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=glm+score%3A5) (GLMs) and (2) [data transformations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=data+transformation+score%3A5). The latter idea unifies your two models and suggests a better way to express the multiplicative model is as an additive error for $\log(y).$

Comment: @whuber I already have some passing familiarity with GLMs, however I am not quite sure how they help me here. Note that I do not want to make **any** assumptions on the distribution of $y$, beyond that it is restricted to the given interval.

Comment: If you are unsure how they help, then start by reviewing logistic regression: the principal reason invoked for its use is that the responses are limited to the interval $[0,1].$  Then look at other response distribution families, including Gamma (restricted to $(0,\infty)$) and Beta (restricted to $[0,1]$).

Comment: @whuber But doesn't logistic regression rather models the case where the variable lives in the open interval (0,1) and not the closed interval [0,1]?

Comment: That's a distinction of absolutely no consequence.  In actuality, logistic regression, *when properly computed,* handles the closed interval just fine.

Comment: @whuber Is it of no consequence? As an example, some of the data I am dealing with could be described as a mixture between some truncated normal distribution on (0, 1) and a dirac measure at 0.

Comment: Those are known as ["zero-inflated" models.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=zero+inflated+score%3A5)  It looks like your focus on the *supports* of distributions might be misdirected and that you are instead concerned about being able to model a particular *kind* of distribution.  Why not ask directly about whatever your statistical problem is?